# remote access privileges (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, remote-access

I have SQL Server running on Linux and I want to access it on SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) in Windows.
Facing this issue!!

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: It shouldn't be using the Named Pipes Provider. If you have SQL Server [version] Configuration Manager installed on the machine from which you're using SSMS, go to SQL Native Client Configuration (32-bit and 64 bit) > Client Protocols and make sure that the TCP/IP protocols are enabled and that they have Order `1` so that they have priority. Failing that, in SSMS's "Connect to Server" dialog, use Server name: `tcp:yourServerNameOrIpAddress`.

Comment: So what have you done so far? Have you enabled remote connections and TCP? Is this a default instance or a named instance? If the latter, have you set a static port, or have you enabled SQL Server Browser?